# What is the correct way to use the phrase 'I'm a bit of a...(noun)'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage, grammaticality

*'I am a little bit of a scientist myself'*. I've heard this phrase so many times but I can't find any grammatical explanation to this. Is it possible, for example, to say *'I'm a little bit of a teacher'* if I want to tell somebody about my profession?

Or if I'm working as both the teacher and the engineer, for example, but I teach more often, can I say *'I'm a little bit of an engineer and a lot of a teacher'*?

Thanks.

Comment: The idiom is ["a bit of a"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20bit%20of%20a/an).

Comment: It means you have the qualities a typical teacher has. It doesn't mean you spend most of your time working as a teacher.

Comment: "I have a certain interest in science". A professional scientist would not say  they were 'a bit of' one.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. You have been very helpful.